# Unable to proxy a private docker registry in Nexus

Tags: nexus3

I'm trying to proxy our private docker registry and it cannot see the image everytime I access it via the proxy with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/docker-current: pinging docker registry returned: error pinging repository, response code 404
```

The hosted docker registry url is (Nexus 3.6.0):

```
https://siteA.com:5000/repository/docker-group
```

The proxy URL is (Nexus 3.7.1):

```
https://siteB.com:5000/repository/docker-group
```

I configured the proxy to use the hosted url and have the firewall ACLs opened between the 2 sites.

Nexus in siteB is running an nginx proxy while siteA is behind a load balancer.

Is there any configurations missing on our part?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by changing the remote URL format.

FROM:

```
https://siteA.com:5000/repository/docker-group
```

TO:

```
https://siteA.com:5000
```